# How to add user input above code

Tags: java, loops, user-input, binary-search

i want to get the user input from user and do non recursive binary search can any one show me how to do it it would be appreciated

```
public class Main {
// binarySeach: non-recursive
   public int Main(int[] a, int x) {
      int low = 0;
  int high = a.length - 1;
  while (low <= high) {
     int mid = (low + high)/2;
     if (a[mid] == x) return mid;
     else if (a[mid] < x) low = mid + 1;
     else high = mid - 1;
  }
  return -1;
  }



 public static void main(String[] args) {
      Main bin = new Main();
  int[] a =
    { 2, 8,12,14,16,19,24,28,31,33,// 0-9
     39,40,45,49,51,53,54,56,57,60,// 10-19
     63,69,77,82,88,89,94,96,97};  // 20-28
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
     System.out.print(bin.Main(a,
        a[i]) + " ");   

  System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: Naming your methods the same as your class is probably never a good idea as it can lead to confusion.

Comment: Please try to search before posting next time...

Comment: Unless this is homework, use Arrays.binarySearch() for the search.

Comment: yeah you right this is for homework, use Arrays.binarySearch() for the search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood, you want to search an inputted value in an array and return its index.

So you first need to get the value from user input then search it in your array like this:

```
public class Main {
     public int Search(int[] a, int x) {
         int low = 0;
         int high = a.length - 1;
         Boolean search=false;
         while (low <= high && !search) {
            int mid = (low + high)/2;
            if (a[mid] == x) {
                search=true;
                return mid;
            }
            else if (a[mid] < x) low = mid + 1;
            else high = mid - 1;
         }
         return -1;
     }


     public static void main(String[] args) {
          Main bin = new Main();
          int[] a ={ 2, 8,12,14,16,19,24,28,31,33,// 0-9
             39,40,45,49,51,53,54,56,57,60,// 10-19
             63,69,77,82,88,89,94,96,97};  // 20-28
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter the number you whould like to search !");
             int n=input.nextInt();
             int index=bin.Search(a,n);
             if(index<0) { //-1 means that the element doesn't exist in the array 
                System.out.println("This number doesn't exist in the array "); 
             } else { //The "}" before the else was missing
                System.out.println("The index of the number "+n+" in the array is :"+ index);
             }

     }
}
```

You need to use `Scanner` to get the user input and you don't need to loop the array to search it, you just need to call your search method and pass the `array` and the `inputted value` as parameters.

**EDIT:**

See the live [**DEMO** here](https://ideone.com/5yAOnm), the input is `8` and the ineex is `1`.

Comment: it works but it gives wrong answers try it your self any way thank you

Comment: @JeromeJacobsFrancis No it works perfectly, I had a typo a `}` was missing before the else statement, and now it works you can see the DEMO with an input equal to `8`.

Comment: yeah it works now thank you very much earlier i have put bracket in the wrong place

Answer (score 5):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main bin = new Main();
    int[] a = { 2, 8,12,14,16,19,24,28,31,33,// 0-9
                39,40,45,49,51,53,54,56,57,60,// 10-19
                63,69,77,82,88,89,94,96,97};  // 20-28
    Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number to search");
    int n = userinput.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Number index: "+bin.Main(a, n));
}
```

Notice first position/index is 0, so if you want to get number index 3 for number 12 instead of index 2, change `System.out.println("Number index: "+bin.Main(a, n));` to `System.out.println("Number index: "(bin.Main(a, n)+1));`

Comment: can you show me how do i add this to my code if u don't mind

Comment: i tried it but im getting errors

Comment: What do you want user to input? The array? The number to search? Both?

Comment: number to search and get the index value